# MYSQL Query on selecting two tables

Tags: mysql

I have a problem in selecting data from two different tables. see example

```
TABLE1
UserID | Name     | Description
myID01 | myname   | mydescription
myID02 | myname2  | mydescription2
myID03 | myname3  | mydescription3

TABLE2
ID | UserID  | Picture        | Pic_Description
1  | myID01  | mypicture.jpg  | This is my picture
```

The output must be to display all the record from TABLE1 and select only the matching UserID from TABLE1 to TABLE2 to display the Picture.

What must be the correct MYSQL statement to display my expected output? Thank you.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to join multiple tables.

```
select t1.UserID as userid, t1.Name as name, t1.Description as description, t2.picture as picture
from table1 as t1
join table2 as t2
on t1.UserID = t2.UserID
```

Comment: ill try it and if im fetching the data by $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query). am i going to call them by $row['t1.UserID']; $row['t2.picture'] ?

Comment: See the update, they now are accessible from `$row['userid']` etc. Those are referred to as aliases.

Comment: Thank you so much chris85. It is now working fine. I'm having a hard time figuring out because i'm using INNER JOIN.

Comment: If unspecified, as is here, this is an inner join. What are you having issues with; or you were having issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
SELECT * -- You can change to your desired column
FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t2.UserId = t1.UserId
```

Comment: You are not selecting `t2.Picture`.

Comment: @Sean yup, actually I don't know what column he wanted, so I made an edit to my post

Comment: The OP states - `... display all the record from TABLE1 and select only the matching UserID from TABLE1 to TABLE2 to display the **Picture**.`